# What does David Dunn's street address (1842) refer to in Glass?

Tags: symbols, unbreakable-trilogy, glass

I just watched M. Night Shyamalan's science fiction thriller [Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_(2019_film)) for the first time yesterday. Then I watched it again today because I just had to. I loved every second and wished all the deleted scenes were in it. I have lots of questions about this last film in the trilogy (Unbreakable, Split and Glass) but the big one right now is what does David Dunn's address *mean*. It's '1842' and the camera lingers on it. When Shyamalan's camera dwells on any image it usually means something and this one has me scratching my head. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Jan 13, [1842](https://www.onthisday.com/events/date/1842). Dr. William Brydon, a surgeon in the British Army during the First Anglo-Afghan War, becomes famous for (reputedly) being the sole survivor of an army of 16,500 when he reaches the safety of a garrison in Jalalabad. - This popped out of a google search as the top result, given Elijah's well know obsessions it seemed freaky, but I don't have anything concrete to provide regarding the director's motivation.

Comment: I'm not sure about the above. It's certainly an interesting story and I recall reading about it but I don't what what it has to do with Glass other than it was someone beating the odds. There was also the 1842 [Lombard Street race riot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lombard_Street_riot) in Philadelphia which is where the movie is set.